# How to get a Fieldvalue only if other fieldvalues in the same document are true

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

How to: If I want to retrieve a FieldValue (String) only if in the same document there is another field (boolean) which is true.
For Example: If I have a Document in Firestore which contains a Field: {name: "Some Name", active: true} and I only want the name to be retrieved if the field "active" is true. Is this possible?
Does this question make sense? Sorry, I'm a self-taught developer and I have difficulties to explain stuff as a coder. But I hope you guys can still understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can run query to filter out the documents you don't want. like:

`query(collection(db, "users"), where("active", "==", true));`

But if you want retrieve a single fieldvalue like "name" and filter out other value in same document like "active" is impossible. firestore only retrieve whole document.